# Errors were encountered while processing libc6:amd64

Tags: kali-linux, dependencies, libraries, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL Kali Linux, then I typed `apt-get update` so when I type `apt-get dist-upgrade` for upgrade then I saw this

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bsdmainutils : Depends: calendar but it is not installed
                Depends: ncal but it is not installed
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.31) but 2.31-2 is installed
            Recommends: manpages but it is not installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install` yet the errors message continued:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  calendar cpp cpp-9 libc-bin libisl22 libmpc3 libmpfr6 ncal
Suggested packages:
  cpp-doc gcc-9-locales
Recommended packages:
  manpages
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  calendar cpp cpp-9 libisl22 libmpc3 libmpfr6 ncal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin
1 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 67 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-2) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Nothing to restart.
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while procesing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Here is the screenshot. I really need help to solve this issue

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1):

Edit the postinst for libc6

```
vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6\:amd64.postinst
```

and comment out the line

```
set -e
```

Rerun the fix-broken

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
```